# Azure Data Factory : Invalid URI: The Uri scheme is too long

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using a Copy activity in Azure Data Factory to copy the data from Http Source to datalake. My Url contains sql query as a query param. Iam getting "Invalid URI: The Uri scheme is too long" error
Possible Error conditions:
SQL query with more select fields and date field in where condition - Error is thrown
SQL query with more select fields and string field in where condition - No Error
SQL query with less select fields and date field in where condition - No Error

API looks like the below one:
http://example.com/api/query?q=select a,b,c,d........ from table where date >= '' and date < ''
I'd appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to the issue mentioned in the below link. Replacing `:` with `%3A` resolved the issue for me.

https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/1318